# Add Username to URL for redirect

Tags: redirect, username

I need a little help with what I believe would be PHP.

http://www.domain.com/author/**username**/achievements/

Depending on the username of the person logged in, I would like to create a URL that redirects a user to the aforementioned page. To do this, **username** needs to be replaced with their logged in username.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has several functions for getting user information, for example the following ones:

- [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)
- [`get_userdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)
- [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_get_current_user()`
This should do the trick:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.domain.com/author/'.$current_user->user_login.'/achievements/');  
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'You have no business being here';
}
```

Also see the [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) documentation.

If you run in a:`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');
function do_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
}
```

Comment: The »logged-in»-check should be done via [`is_user_logged_in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Comment: Yes I agree. I changed my answer

Comment: Note that output buffering rarely is needed, just do your redirect early enough, so before the header has been send. @JimFender